# @AfterMethod being ignored when rerunning test in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm trying to build logic into my test suite so that if a test fails, it automatically gets rerun. When my test fails, it gets rerun as expected, but
my test suite contains an @AfterMethod which seems to be getting ignored when the test is getting rerun.

I've followed the solution given here:

https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/run-failed-test-cases-using-testng/

So I created the 2 classes:

```
package softwareTestingMaterial;

import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer; import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class RetryFailedTestCases implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private int retryCnt = 0;
    private int maxRetryCnt = 2;


public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
    if (retryCnt < maxRetryCnt) {
        System.out.println("Retrying " + result.getName() + " again and the count is " + (retryCnt+1));
        retryCnt++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

And

```
package softwareTestingMaterial;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

public class RetryListenerClass implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation testannotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod)  {
        IRetryAnalyzer retry = testannotation.getRetryAnalyzer();

        if (retry == null)  {
            testannotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryFailedTestCases.class);
        }

    }
}
```

My XML file for executing the tests looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Test Suite 1">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2" />
        <listener class-name="CustomUtils.RetryListenerClass" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Test 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="WebTests.CheckoutTestWeb"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When @Test throws exceptions, @AfterMethod may not run. To ensure @AfterMethod to be executed, add **alwaysRun** attribute which will look like **@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)**